# Where can I find custom themes for Google Sites

Tags: themes, google-sites

I'm trying to create a custom background theme for a Google Sites site.  Awhile back I did some googling and found some sites with a background image and instructions of how to change table dimensions to create a google sites make shift theme. I can no longer find any of these themes anywhere.  Does anyone know where I can find these templates or instructions how to create my own themes?

Comment: despite the question being so old I feel it doesn't belong here on SO, I think it should be moved to a more appropriate site of the network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing and came accross:

> You can't upload your own themes, only
>   the ones provided by Google.  You can
>   change the background images and most
>   of the colours on the site however. 
>   One of the other users on this forum
>   has made this own "themes" this way
>   and provided instructions

However, you can create [Page Templates](http://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-howtos/page-templates) and then use that custom layout for multiple pages.