# How to create a custom Google Sites theme?

Tags: themes, google-sites

I would like to create a custom theme.  It is possible to apply other people's custom themes (http://www.gethemes.com/free-themes) but I cannot find documentation on how to create Google Sites themes.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522665/where-can-i-find-custom-themes-for-google-sites

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately the answers for that question are not up to date, and I do not feel the questioner came across as clearly as possible. For these reasons, I am creating another question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how to create a entirely custom theme from scratch, but you *can* create a theme that is extremely "customized". In other words, you can create a new site, apply an existing theme, then customize colors, fonts, and background images (or textures) for all the various parts of the page. You will not be able to change the size of the various elements (sidebar, header area, etc), but as long as you can find a base theme with the general layout that you'd like, you're set. You are then free to publish your new theme as a template.
If this provides the flexibility that you hoped for, here are the required steps:

1. Create a new Site. This will be the basis for your theme.
2. From the "More" button/menu, select "Manage Site".
3. On the left column, select "Themes" (bottom of list)
4. Take a look at the pre-built theme catalog on the page. You will need to choose one for your "base theme". (Simply note the name of your chosen theme at this point). Once you have decided on a base theme, click the link at the top of page titled, "Build Your Own Custom Theme".
5. From the "Base Theme" drop-down, select the theme you chose on the previous step.
6. Now you are free to customize colors, fonts, and background images (or textures) for all the various parts of the page. (This process will not allow you to change the size of the various elements, which is why it is important to choose a base theme with the general layout that you'd like.)
7. Finally, return to the "Manage Sites" page, and under the "General" tab, look for the button labeled "Publish this site as a template", and follow the instructions found there (naming the template, etc).

UPDATE: You can find similar instructions in the [official documentation](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156651).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question:How to create a custom Google Sites theme?

Comment: @Andaero, I've edited my answer to make it clearer, but this is in fact the officially documented way to "[Build your own custom theme](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156651)" (also known as "templates").

Comment: I mean... you follow that link, and it goes to a page called "Site Templates", I was expecting the page to have the title that you used to link to that URL -- "Build your own custom theme".